# find top 100 values by each group in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Hi I have a data like this (Tablename: topcount)

```
    ID     Value       Count_total
    1      Sam         3008
    1      Sarah       5677
    3      Gil         3455
    2      Gil         4555
...
```

I want to find the count of top 100 values for each ID.

I have tried this so far -

> ```
> with top1000 as
> (select ID, 
> ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(count_total) ORDER BY count_total DESC LIMIT 1000) as top
> from topcount
> group by app_id)
>
> select app_id, sum(top.count_total)
> from top1000
> ```

How to I efficiently write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from your_table
qualify row_number() over(partition by ID order by Count_total desc) <= 100
```